# Statistical Significance of a Binary Event

Tags: statistical-significance, binary-data

Consider a retail bank that makes loans to consumers.  Some consumers will default on their loans.  Modeling the default event would typically be modeled with a logistic regression if I am not
mistaken.  The default event could happen at any time after loan origination, so it could happen after not making any payments (in which case it would be deemed a “first payment default”) or it could happen after the consumer has made at least one payment.

If I have 100,000 loans and 200 of them are associated with defaults, of which 100 are first payment defaults, how would I determine whether first payment defaults are actually just happening randomly or if they reflect statistically significant events?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean be "happening randomly"? Do you mean whether there is a higher probability that if someone defaults their loan he does so before the first payment?

Comment: Good question - I'm not totally clear myself on that.  I guess I am wondering a few things:

Comment: 1) How could I determine if the number of FPDs is concerning?  i..e, does it indicate that the bank is making bad loans?  Or should I expect that of all defaults, around half of them would be FPDs typically?
2) If I have 100 FPDs out of 100,000 loans, then the sample PD would be 0.20% - what would a logistic regression tell me?  Would it tell me if the 0.20% is statistically significant?  Would it tell me if the 0.20% is a good reflection of the theoretical population?
3) Should the response be Default with the specific type of FPD as a predictor? Or would FPD be the response?

Comment: For 1) you'll need domain knowledge. What percentages of first payment default would indicate that the bank does bad loans? Ideally you should figure this out before you look at the data. Then you can use a one sided binomial test to figure out if this is the case for this bank. 2) for logistic regression you'd need more explanatory variables (e.g. information about the customers of each loan etc.) You could then tackle two questions: Why do people default (inference) and what can we say about new customers, e.g. whether they will default (prediction).

Comment: Thanks Stefan - I appreciate your help.